# C# extract two elements of a string using a RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, string

I've got the following string which I extracted from a `POST` request using `.Split()`.

I need to extract the e-mail (`login_email=`) and the password (`login_password=`).

```
login_cmd=&login_params=&login_email=my%40mail.de&login_password=TOPsecret&submit..........
```

All in all I need to get:

```
my%40mail.de

TOPsecret
```

Is there an easy way, maybe without using RegEx, or is writing a RegEx for this easy to learn? I know the RegEx for extracting the e-mail address should start after `login_email=` and stop at the `&` sign.

Comment: So you have `TOPsecret` password in query string, That is probably a *bigger* issue.

Comment: I don't understand you. The data I showed is not useable.

Comment: If you're within the context of a request to the server, the [`Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) object has properties (`QueryString`, `Form` etc) that are specifically designed for getting this information

Comment: This is all on clientside, not on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lookarounds like below.

```
(?<=login_(?:email|password)=)[^&]*(?=&)
```

OR

```
(?<=login_(?:email|password)=)[^&]*
```

Lookafter to login_email= or login_password and match any character but not of `&` zero or more times.

```
String input = @"login_cmd=&login_params=&login_email=my%40mail.de&login_password=TOPsecret&submit..........";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=login_(?:email|password)=)[^&]*");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/AFFpLq)

```
String input = @"login_cmd=&login_params=&login_email=my%40mail.de&login_password=TOPsecret&submit..........";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=login_email=)([^&]+)|(?<=login_password=)([^&]+)");

foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
    if(!m.Groups[1].Value.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email : " + m.Groups[1].Value);
    }
        if(!m.Groups[2].Value.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Password : " + m.Groups[2].Value);
    }
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/AFFpLq)

Comment: Works great, is there any way, to get the type of field (username or password), to get an output like: username: xxx password:xyz

Answer (score 6):

I would say the easiest is to not use regex, but use the built in HttpUtility:

```
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("login_email");
```

Simples.

Comment: Was about to write that. People always want to utilize Regex, cause without reading the API they don't know about build in functionality already matching all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=login_email=)[^&]+|(?<=login_password=)[^&]+
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/16

Comment: I'm new to RegEx, how to use the RegEx above on my example?